# ctest cannot run with simple command

Tags: cmake, ctest

I have the ctest setting and work fine with all executable I've built for the project. The problem is I want to add some test with a system command, it has nothing to do with program in the solution, I cannot get it run by ctest.

I added a simple test as below, it just run the command **echo**:

```
add_test(NAME toto_test COMMAND echo bla bla bla)
```

Then the when I run ctest, I got the error

```
Start  1: toto_test
Could not find executable echo
Looked in the following places:
echo
echo.exe
Release/echo
Release/echo.exe
Release/echo
Release/echo.exe
Unable to find executable: echo
1/10 Test  #1: toto_test ........................***Not Run   0.00 sec

The following tests FAILED:
      1 - toto_test (Not Run)
Errors while running CTest
```

And when I run ctest with verbose option, I get

```
Constructing a list of tests
Done constructing a list of tests
Updating test list for fixtures
Added 0 tests to meet fixture requirements
Checking test dependency graph...
Checking test dependency graph end
test 1
    Start 1: toto_test
Could not find executable echo
Looked in the following places:
echo
echo.exe
Release/echo
Release/echo.exe
Release/echo
Release/echo.exe

1: Test command:  "bla" "bla" "bla"
Unable to find executable: echo
1/1 Test #1: toto_test ........................***Not Run   0.00 sec

0% tests passed, 1 tests failed out of 1

Total Test time (real) =   0.02 sec

The following tests FAILED:
      1 - toto_test (Not Run)
Errors while running CTest
```

Can anyone come to help please.
Thanks a lot

Comment: you should try `FIND_PROGRAM()` or `${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo` it will be much more portable

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to do it. For the general purpose of running a test with an external program, use add_custom_target, then use ${CMAKE_COMMAND} to build this target when running the tests :

```
add_custom_target(run_toto COMMAND echo bla bla bla)
add_test(NAME test_toto COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build . --target run_toto)
```